# android trying to figure out how to create a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification in android. The icon gets displyed, and the text vaneshed.  Also when you click it the Intent does not get called. (I have a test intent that should bring up the web browser).
I cannot figure out why the text goes away and when I click the sttus bar, the browser does not come up.
code

```
public class Welcome extends Activity
{
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(
                R.drawable.icon, "Click Me!", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification Details...";
        CharSequence contentText = "Ted";
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 
                android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, 
                contentText, intent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notifyDetails);
    }
}
```

Ted

Answer (score 0):

You could try initializing your `notifyIntent` with the

```
new Intent(packageContext:Context, cls:Class<?>)
```

constructor.

To see how the `new Intent(action:String, uri:Uri)` works, please see the [overview of the Intent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).